# Man wakes up in a dark corridor, can’t remember why he’s a prisoner

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Recently I’ve been thinking of an old science fiction short story that I read between roughly twenty and thirty years ago and that I would read again: it was published probably in the Fifties or Sixties and I seem to remember it was written by an established author.

It was short, possibly very short: and although I don’t remember how it ended, I have a feeling it hadn’t a happy ending.

The little I can remember about the plot pivots on an unnamed man - a prisoner probably - who wakes up in a long, empty, black or dark corridor: maybe he’s bound, maybe not; he doesn’t know why he’s prisoner and how he’s wound up there. As he explores the corridor, new sections open, possibly endlessly.
As far as I remember, there wasn't much else in the story: just the man, the corridor and his thoughts.

I can add that somehow I used to pair this story in my mind with Plato’s allegory of the cave but I'm unsure how much this can be helpful.

Comment: Can you include any details of why you remember this as being a science fiction story?

Comment: If Theodore Sturgeon's "What Dead Men Tell" is the one you're looking for, you can read it in the November 1949 *Astounding* at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v44n03_1949-11_cape1736/page/n121/mode/1up).

Comment: @WiggotheWookie An _endless_ corridor seems SFF-nal to me.

Comment: user14111: I've skimmed through it and it feels like the story I'm looking for! My memories are faded but a few passages here and there ring a bell, so I'd say this is the one! If you add an answer I'll accept it at once. Thank you for your help!